# Exchange Powershell with administrative account from BASTION forest

Tags: powershell, exchange

Does anybody know of a way to get the Exchange Powershell module working when using an admin account over a one-way trust?
The Exchange server is located in the USER domain and the administrative accounts is located in the BASTION domain.
The USER domain trusts the BASTION domain but not vice versa (a classic on-way trust).
The Exchange Powershell module seems to have an issue with users not being in the same domain as it. I have all the privileges in form of groups required for the user from the BASTION domain.

To connect to the Exchange Powershell module i'm using:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "http://exchsrv0001.contoso.com/powershell" -Authentication Kerberos -Name "Exchange2016"
```

Which gives the following Powershell error:

```
New-PSSession : [exch0001.contoso.com] Processing data from remote server exch0001.contoso.com failed with the following error message: [ClientAccessServer=exch0001,BackEndServer=exch0001.contoso.com,RequestId=7e00d1c3-6002-4d6d-a07b-cf6c51dd503e,TimeStamp=5/5/2021 2:51:35 PM] 
[AuthZRequestId=9c7a24a7-0236-4de6-aa16-2cddec305b45][FailureCategory=AuthZ-CmdletAccessDeniedException] The operation couldn't be performed because 'BASTION\admuser' couldn't be found. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Error from the application log:

```
(Process w3wp.exe, PID 14720) "RBAC authorization returns Access Denied for user BASTION\admuser (SID=S-1-5-21-***-***-***-1167). Reason: User was not found on Domain Controller DC00002.contoso.com."
```

So it looks like it is only looking in it's own Domain for the user and ignoring trusts and foreign security principals for that matter since I tried converting the Organization Management group to Domain Local and add members to it from BASTION domain but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For the remote computer is not in a trusted domain, the remote computer may not be able to authenticate your credentials. Try adding the remote computer to the list of trusted hosts for trust:

```
winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="<RemoteComputer>"}'
```

Check if the following similar thread about the trusted hosts which **Niko.Cheng** mentioned is helpful to you: **[Connecting to Exchange Powershell from a different domain](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ce5da7e9-35f5-4d68-a98e-4ab4e0c01990/connecting-to-exchange-powershell-from-a-different-domain?forum=exchangesvradmin)**

Or you could enter the **User** credential instead of the credential from another domain to connect to Exchange server powershell: **[Connect to a remote Exchange server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell?view=exchange-ps#connect-to-a-remote-exchange-server)**

Comment: Thing is though that I can PSRemote regularly just fine, it’s the configuration Microsoft.Exchange that doesn’t work. And no I don’t wanna enter user credentials since that would defeat the purpose of the Bastion domain.

Comment: Is adding trusted host helpful to fix the remote session issue?

Comment: No it does not because it is not WinRM that is the issue, it’s the exchange module.